# Free online alternatives to the Khan Academy

Tags: statistics, self-learning, education, learning

What is considered the most efficient way to learn statistics online for free?

Usually The Khan Academy is considered but since they have got some serious complaints* I am looking for overlooked alternatives.

[*] https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/answer-sheet/post/how-well-does-khan-academy-teach/2012/07/25/gJQA9bWEAX_blog.html

Also:
https://learnandteachstatistics.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/khan-not-good/

Comment: I did not read the first but the sound link is kind of rubbish, I think it say watch my videos not his. Though i seriously don't like khan academy's videos and, did not recommend anyone to watch. 

I think a well written book is the best way to learn. 
But you can try https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/ ,may satisfy your needs.

Comment: For probability background of statistics, consider Grinstead and Snell. Available in book form, but free PDF from Dartmouth available.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear that you don't like Khan Academy since I use it quite frequently to brush up on trivial operations in DE and Linear Algebra.

As for learning statistics, I think you should check out this on Quora: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-learn-basic-statistics

Ironically, the link does contain suggestions to use Khan Academy to learn stats.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest checking out Beestar. It is an online platform, which means students can access it from anywhere with an internet connection. This flexibility allows students to study and practice at their own pace and convenience, fitting the learning into their schedule. It’s user-friendly interface and interactive can make the learning experience more engaging and enjoyable. It emphasizes skill development through interactive practice. The platform offers a variety of exercises, quizzes, and challenges that help students enhance their critical thinking, problem-solving, and analytical skills.